# Does site collection backup , also backup any custom web parts

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, backup

I have created a custom web part inside my visual studio 2012, and i publish it to a site collection. now i have backup the site collection to move it to another server. but my question is, if I backup the site collection also backup any custom web parts?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would throw errors at you if the web part is not deployed as a feature on the destination server. You need to package the web part via the Publish option, then use powershell to deploy the feature on the destination server and any errors present will no longer appear.